# Hosting Video on sever and playing them on jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, video, video-streaming

I want to embed and play a video file on my jsp page. 
What i did, i make one jsp and i put the below tag on that :

```
<EMBED SRC="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home/Hibernate.mp4" WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="100" AUTOPLAY="TRUE" LOOP="true"></EMBED>
```

But the problem is it always try to find the video in my war file i.e. if i kept the video on my war file as following folder structure /home/Hibernate.mp4 then only i can play that .

But i need many videos to be get played on my jsp, so want to keep all videos on my server at some place.

So what should i do to play these. Should i make use of servlet and then read the bytes of videos and put them on out.println...

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a servlet guy.
consider movies are located at server under `/home/movie` path.
So you need to provide a servlet which open the desired movie and response it to the client.
for example, client requests `http://127.0.0.1:8080/showmov?name=pulse1995.mpg`
here `/showmov` is a servlet, and this servlet just get the request parameter(`id`) and search in inside the movie folder and response it.

```
package test;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/showmov")
public class ShowMovie extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        if(id!=null && !id.equals("")){
          FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("/home/moview/"+id);
          response.setContentType("movie/mpeg");//not sure about this mime type
          response.setContentLength((int) fis.getChannel().size());
          int r;
          byte[] buff=new byte[1024];
          while((r=fis.read(buff))==buff.length){
            response.getOutputStream().write(buff);
          }
          response.getOutputStream().write(buff,0,r);
          response.getOutputStream().flush();
        }else{
          //maybe show a list
        }
    }
}
```